# Image Processing Mag and Phase Spectrum of Sobel, Roberts Mask

Tags: image-processing

How to find the Magnitude and Phase Spectrum of Sobel, Roberts etc. etc. Mask of Image Processing using MATHEMATICA 9.0 platform....

Comment: Would you min detailing your question?

Comment: I agree the question is unclear.

Answer (score 6):

You can find most of the definitions for these filters by googling, and once you know the definition it can be put directly into the [`GradientFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GradientFilter.html) command using the `Method` option:

```
im = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "JellyBeans"}];
```

**Sobel**

```
GradientFilter[im, 
 Method -> {{{1, 0, -1}, {2, 0, -2}, {1, 0, -1}}/
    4., {{1, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {-1, -2, -1}}/4.}]
```

[image: sobel]

**Roberts**

```
GradientFilter[im, Method -> {{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}]
```

[image: roberts]

**Prewitt**

```
GradientFilter[im, 
 Method -> {{{1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 
     0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}]
```

[image: Prewitt]

**Edit: phase information**

To get the phase of the gradient, one could use [`ImageConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageConvolve.html), and if you want the syntax to be analogous to the above `GradientFilter`, a function could be defined like this:

```
Options[phaseFilter] = {
   Method -> {{{1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}}, {{-1, -1, -1}, {0,
        0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}
   };

phaseFilter[im_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{method = OptionValue[Method]},
  Image@Rescale@
    MapThread[ArcTan, ImageData[ImageConvolve[im, #]] & /@ method]
  ]

phaseFilter[im, Method -> {{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}]
```

[image: colors]

The default method is the **Prewitt** filter (if you don't specify any `Method` explicitly).

This does the convolution in each color channel. It may make more sense to first convert to grayscale:

```
phaseFilter[ColorConvert[im, "Graylevel"], 
 Method -> {{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}}]
```

[image: phase in gray]

Comment: Ok its nice information, but still I m not getting.. because I want to find the Fourier Spectrum of Sobel,  Roberts, etc. Mask, and then MULTIPLY with the Fourier Spectrum of the Input Image, to get the Output Image after Inverse Fourier Transformation.

Comment: What you're describing is just an application of the **convolution theorem**. It is made unnecessary if you do the convolution directly using `ImageConvolve`. What I did in my answer is **equivalent** to what you describe.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `Fourier` to calculate the fourier transform of a filter:

```
filter = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
(* move anchor to 1/1 and pad to 32x32 *)
filterPaddingAnchored = RotateLeft[PadRight[filter, {32, 32}], {1, 1}];
ft = Fourier[filterPaddingAnchored];
```

and `MatrixPlot` to show the results:

```
Row[MatrixPlot[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {Abs[ft], Arg[ft]}]
```

[image]

or any other plotting function you like:

```
Row[ListPlot3D[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {Abs[ft], Arg[ft]}]
```

[image]

Comment: ThankU very much for Ur time and Reply....One more thing I want to ask is that "The two-dimensional Fractional Fourier Transform" available in the Wolfram Demonstrations is same as Prof. Haldun Ozaktas, Prof. S. C. Pei has established in their Research Papers....or its VERY different.....

Comment: Looks like you understood what was being asked - I was mislead by the reference to image processing, but all it was seems to be an FT... +1

Comment: Again sorry for asking the Question about MMA....If one has to MULTPLY two different Magnitude and Phase Spectra both, to get the new Magnitude and Phase Spectra, then which command to use......

Comment: @user8727: Not trying to be rude, but you should really get an introductory book about MMA and read it cover to cover. Having to ask basic stuff like "how do I multiply two things" must be annoying for you too, and the resulting answers aren't helpful to anyone else. That's why your questions get closed or downvoted: A Q&A-site like this can't replace a good tutorial, introductory course or book. It's simply the wrong format. I can recommend "Programming in MMA" by Maeder and "Programming with MMA" by Wellin.